# updating label of a bigquery table/view

Tags: google-bigquery, bq

I am trying to add a label to my bigquery table/view using the following bq command.

bq update --set_label primary_keys:a,b project-id:dataset.tablename

The command works perfectly fine if I have only one key (a) as the primary key. However, when I try to insert multiple keys (a,b) separated by comma then it throws an invalid characters error. Is there a way to add multiple keys within the same label separated by comma.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is feasible, thus comma character is not accepted there, according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/labels-intro):

> Keys and values can contain only lowercase letters, numeric
>   characters, underscores, and dashes. All characters must use UTF-8
>   encoding, and international characters are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/labels-intro), labels are key-value pairs that helps you organize your Google Cloud BigQuery resources.

Being a key-value pair is a requirement as per the documentation, and this is not compatible with your intention of giving two different values to the same key.